# Why we are using mac address in data link layer instead of ip address though ip address itself is unique within a network?

Tags: networking

Though ip address is unique,what is the need of mac address.I am confused.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

MAC addresses are used by some, not all, layer-2 protocols, and of those that do use MAC addresses, some use 48-bit MAC addresses, and some use 64-bit MAC addresses.

I assume you are referring to ethernet, which uses 48-bit MAC addresses. Ethernet, as a set of layer-1/2 protocols knows nothing about layer-3 protocols (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.). Ethernet is more than happy to carry any layer-3 protocol, and layer-3 protocols are unaware of which layer-2 protocol (ethernet, token ring FDDI, PPP, Wi-Fi frame relay, HDLC, etc.) carries it, and that can change along the entire path.

You need to understand the differences between the network layers. Locally, your layer-3 packets are encapsulated and carried in layer-2 frames. The layer-2 protocols are responsible for delivering their payloads (layer-3 packets) on the LAN. Layer-3 protocols are responsible for delivering their payloads (layer-4, e.g. TCP segments) between LANs. Layer-4 protocols are responsible for delivering their payloads (application protocols/data) between applications.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good, but I would like more explanation of what the MAC address is used for (and, therefore, why is it needed) on the 2nd layer.

Comment: There are multiple questions and answers about this on [networkengineering.se], which is really the SE site for such a question. For example, [Reason for both a MAC and an IP address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3329/8499), [Why do we need MAC Address if we can uniquely identify each machine with an IP Address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/34765/8499), and [Why do we need local MAC address when there is a globally unique MAC address for every machine?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/42829/8499), among others.

Comment: There are a lot of *questions* about that, but I couldn't find a satisfactory *answer* yet. People say "MAC is on layer 2, IP is on layer 3", but they don't answer what the MAC address is actually used for. I've supposed it is used to perform some logic and take some action based on that. What logic and which action is what I would like to know ;)

Comment: It is a layer-2 address. Each host on a LAN that uses MAC addressing has a unique MAC address, and layer-2 frames are delivered host-to-host on the LAN using the MAC address. The alternative would be to broadcast everything to all hosts on the LAN, and that is unsupportable.

Comment: @RafaelEyng, you could pose your question on [Netwrok Engineering Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations) which is for discussions. If you join [networkengineering.se] you will have enough reputation to participate in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

Because mac address is physical, known only within the network and thus frames need to be converted into packets which also contain routing info in their headers to connect with different networks like internet.Thus network layer comes in responsible for logical addressing to make the packets transferable across networks.The whole purpose is utilize the tcp/ip protocol and create less overheads on the physical network.